# Is it possible to remove columns in select query

Tags: c#, linq

As the question suggests I want to remove the columns from a select query where in that column are empty.

```
var query = from a in ...
select new
{
    A =(decimal?)null,
    B =(decimal?)null,
    C = a.Amount1
};

var query2 = from b in ...
select new
{
    A = b.Amount2,
    B = b.Amount3,
    C = (decimal?)null
};

var query3 = query.Concat(query2);
```

**Output:**

```
query3=[0]{A=null, B=null, C=100.00}
       [1]{A=100.00, B=50.25, C=null}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
query3=[0]{C=100.00}
       [1]{A=100.00, B=50.25}
```

Comment: What do you mean "where in that column are empty"?

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ query *typically* outputs objects of a common type, so each object has to have the same base type (and the columns associated.  The only way to concatenate objects of different types is to cast them to `object`:

```
var query = from a in ...
select new
{
    C = a.Amount1
};

var query2 = from b in ...
select new
{
    A = b.Amount2,
    B = b.Amount3,
};

var query3 = query.Cast<object>().Concat(query2.Cast<object>());
```

but since they're anonymous you'll have to use `dynamic` to access them since you won;t be able to cast back to the original type, so you'll end up with something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)(query3[0])).C);
Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)(query3[1])).A);
```

or at best:

```
dynamic list = query3.ToList();
Console.WriteLine(list[0].C);
Console.WriteLine(list[1].A);
```

but in any case you'll lose compile-time type safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The result set has to contain items of the same type and even if fields are null they still have to be there.

You could not show them in your UI, but exactly how you do that will depend on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A class has a predefined set of fields (not to speak about `ExpandoObject` which has some compiler tricks going on). This is the same for anonymous type, which you use.

You can't just hide or remove fields which are not filled. What if you iterate over the instances and try to retrieve `item.C`, which was null and thus removed? That would normally give you a compiler error. How would .NET resolve that?

The only other thing you can do is put in two different types in your list (a list of objects, so untyped), a very bad idea in my opinion. Keep it like this. You could add an indicator which type the row is, to be able to test it easily.

So:

```
select new
{
    Type = "A", // or "B"
    A =(decimal?)null,
    B =(decimal?)null,
    C = a.Amount1
};
```